# Estimating $ p $ for a sequence of random variables $ X_1 \sim B(N_1, p), \ldots, X_k \sim B(N_k, p) $ when I have one realization for each

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

Let $ X_1, \ldots, X_k $ be independent random variables such that $ X_1 \sim B(N_1, p), \ldots, X_k \sim B(N_k, p) $. I have exactly one realization for each, i. e. a sequence $ x_1, \ldots, x_k $ where $ x_i $ is a realization of $ X_i $. (We could generalize, but let's keep things simple, since I don't need anything more complicated.) I know $ N_1, \ldots, N_k $, but I'm trying to estimate $ p $. I'm thinking that using $ \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i/N_i $ would not be ideal, because the $ X_i $'s don't necessarily have the same variance. My intuition is that this estimator is unbiased but has a larger variance than necessary. Thus, I'm thinking that I should use a weighted average to estimate $ p $, where $ x_i/N_i $ is given more weight than $ x_j/N_j $ if $ N_i < N_j $ because then $ \sigma_i^2 = N_ip(1 - p) < \sigma_j = N_jp(1 - p) $. However, I'm not sure exactly what's the estimator I should use, so I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know how to show that $X=X_1+\cdots+X_k\sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N_1+\cdots+N_k, p)\text{?}$

If so you have one observation, $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(N,p)$ where $N=N_1+\cdots+N_k.$

The conditional distribution of $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ given the value of their sum $X$ can be shown not to depend on $p.$ Therefore learning the values of $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ after knowing $X$ does not give you more information about $p$ in addition to what you had when you only knew $X.$

Comment: Thanks, this nicely complements @Arash's answer, and it's a more economical solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use maximum likelihood formulation of the problem:
$$
\hat p=\arg\max_{p\in[0,1]}P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_k=x_k\mid p).
$$
Using the independence of $X_i$'s we have:
\begin{split}
P(X_1=x_1,\dots,X_k=x_k\mid p)&=\prod_{i=1}^k P(X_i=x_i\mid p)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N_i}{x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{N_i-x_i}.
\end{split}
The maximum likelihood formulation is then equivalent to:
$$
\hat p=\arg\max_{p\in[0,1]}\prod_{i=1}^k\binom{N_i}{x_i}p^{x_i}(1-p)^{N_i-x_i}
$$
which is :
$$
\hat p=\arg\max_{p\in[0,1]}\sum_{i=1}^k({x_i}\log p+({N_i-x_i})\log(1-p)).
$$
Solving this will give:
$$
\hat{p}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^k N_i}.
$$
As you can check the estimator is unbiased.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Here is how I was thinking about it. Since $ E() $ is linear, it's trivial to show that any weighted average of the $ X_i/N_i $'s is unbiased. But I wasn't sure how to choose the weights so as to minimize the variance of the estimator.

Comment: It's also clear now that my intuition was completely off. We should give $ x_i/N_i $ _less_ weight than $ x_j/N_j $ if $ N_i < N_j $, since your solution is equivalent with $ \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{N_i}{\sum_{j=1}^{k} N_j}\frac{x_i}{N_i} $, i. e. the weighted average with $ \frac{N_i}{\sum_{j=1}^{k} N_j} $ as weights. It makes perfect sense when I think about it.

Comment: It's true that, if $ N_i < N_j $, then $ \operatorname{Var}(X_i) < \operatorname{Var}(X_j) $, but $ \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{X_i}{N_i}\right) = \frac{1}{N_i^2}\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \frac{1}{N_i^2}N_ip(1 - p) > \operatorname{Var}\left(\frac{X_j}{N_i}\right) = \frac{1}{N_j^2}\operatorname{Var}(X_j) = \frac{1}{N_j^2}N_jp(1 - p) $ and that's what I care about. I just didn't think enough when I wrote my question!